# Saved form when submitted creates duplicate

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, infopath-rules, information-management

Is there an easy way to prevent a form from creating a duplicate when submitting a saved form?

Comment: By only clicking the submit-button once? ;-) Sorry, about that, but what actually happens to the form on submit?

Comment: Can you elaborate please?  Are you attempting to edit the existing entry?  How are you choosing to name your form?  Is it using the now() function? Sorry for all the questions but this will allow the community to hone in on the nature of the question.

Comment: A customer goes in begins the form and would like to save it because they do not have all the information to complete the form at the time they save the form and come back to it later. The save has created an original record of the document for them to access, however when they submit the form it creates an additional record. Is there a way to prevent the second copy from being made?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you were managing documents instead of Forms you would use 'Require Check-in'.  However, [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/108243/check-in-check-out-for-sharepoint-list-items) suggests using versioning to manage the issue instead.

You also have to think about how each Form (item) is named - a 'naming convention'.  If each item is named you can prevent duplicates from being saved.  Go in list settings>select one a column (e.g. Title)>Enforce Unique Values. This will prevent a new item being saved using the same value.  The Value 'format' can be defined by site admin e.g. 2017-11-24-A, the next item is saved as 2017-11-24-B and so on.